# Сортировка слов js

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать слово по алфавиту с исключением повторяющихся букв.

допустим, есть слово `трафарет` -> будет `аертф`.

то, что к слову можно обращаться как к массиву я в курсе, но `.sort()` не применяется.

Comment: `str.split("")` -> массив букв

Comment: `string.split('').sort().join('')`

Comment: не совсем догнал..разбиваем строку сплитом по сепаратору пустота ??

Comment: @pirogi, а тест провести слабо?

Comment: Как насчёт прописных и строчных букв? Из "Алфавит" вы готовы получить "Аавилтф"?

Comment: нет, хотелось бы чтобы А и а воспринимались как одно и тоже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
var original = 'трафарет',
    sorted = '',
    res = '';

sorted = original.split('').sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
}).join('');

for (var i = 0, l = sorted.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (res.indexOf(sorted[i]) > -1) {
        continue;
    }

    res += sorted[i];
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Условие у меня правильное. Я проверяю не является ли последняя буква _результата_ текущей в отсортированной строке. Хотя `indexOf(sorted[i])` действительно короче :-) Исправил.

Comment: есть небольшая избыточность: каждая буква ищется по всему собранному на тот момент алфавиту. Не используете то, что строка уже отстортирована.

Comment: @Sergiks, согласен. Можно использовать в условии `res.length > 0 && res[res.length - 1] === sorted[i]`, это быстрее, но хуже читается.

Comment: @Sergiks: а так и было, это я не понял сначала и спутал автора ответа indexOf  :)

Comment: @shatal, если выбирать между читаемостью кода и скоростью его выполнения (в разумных пределах, конечно) я выбираю читаемость. Именно по этому я и оставил `indexOf` :-)

Comment: Если в стоке есть буква `Ё` то скрипт работает не правильно.

Comment: Да, действительно. Исправил алгоритм сортировки

Answer (score 1):

Отсортировать, затем исключить повторы:

```
function letters( word) {
    var alphabet = word.split('').sort().join('')
        ,i
        ,prev
        ,out=''
    ;

    for(i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++) {
        if( prev==alphabet.charAt(i)) continue;
        prev = alphabet.charAt(i);
        out = out + prev;
    }
    return out;
}

document.body.innerHTML = letters('трафарет'); // аертф
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/tz907ksj/)